# use of the ConfigureServices and Configure methods in Startup.cs in asp.net vnext

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to understand better the differences between the ConfigureServices and Configure methods in the startup.cs class.
  Comparing the startup class of the starter app and musicstore app from github seems to be configured in a very different way, so I don't understand very well which is the difference and what must be done inside each one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ConfigureServices` method is used to configure the DI container and its services. The `Configure` method is usually used to configure the pipeline.